# How to list all foreign servers?

Tags: postgresql

How to list all foreign servers in a Postgres database from psql command line?
Servers can be created by [create server](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/index.html)

Answer (score 54):

You can query the system catalog [pg_foreign_server](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-foreign-server.html), e.g.:

```
select 
    srvname as name, 
    srvowner::regrole as owner, 
    fdwname as wrapper, 
    srvoptions as options
from pg_foreign_server
join pg_foreign_data_wrapper w on w.oid = srvfdw;

      name      |  owner   |   wrapper    |                options                 
----------------+----------+--------------+----------------------------------------
 csv_server     | postgres | file_fdw     | 
 foreign_server | postgres | postgres_fdw | {host=localhost,port=5432,dbname=test}
(2 rows)
```

Comment: I tried but it needs some special permission:
ERROR:  permission denied for relation pg_authid

Comment: I've updated the query so that it doesn't need read access to `pg_authid.`

Comment: Although I ran this statement as DBA (postgres), this did *not* list all foreign servers. I assume it has something to do with the access priviliges. The list is empty on the foreign server that is not shown. I found it the psql way described by @AndongZhan.

Comment: @SebastianH - This is very strange given that the `\des` command in `psql` produces practically the same query as the one in my answer. You can check this by running `psql` with the option `-E`.

Comment: @klin Thanks for making me question this behavior again :) It turned out that the reason was, that my session was connected to the wrong database (on the same host). I figured this out with `SELECT current_database();`.
Funny: this is a bug in the database client I am using (dbeaver). I will report it :)

Answer (score 42):

I just learn from an expert that we can type

```
\des+
```

[RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM): [display meta-commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-CROSSTABVIEW) :-)

Comment: Or ```\des``` for a more brief version.

Comment: Also relevant information might be: Use the psql client as DBA/postgres, connect to the relevant database with `\c dbname` and then use `\des`.

Comment: If you dont want to answer dont.  No need to tell someone to RTFM, that is the answer to every question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @AaronM In fact, it is not - just as a side note. While there is nothing to say against a reminder to keep the discourse polite, hinting at the immediate availability of the requested information through consulting official docs in a trivial way has its merits too, for the inquirer as much as for everyone else using this site. I this particular case, btw, the inquirer would take offense on himself ... ;)

Comment: I found the help information and documentation to be very wanting so when I landed here and someone said RTFM I had a problem with that.